# How to tie a DLL to the project Config file

Tags: .net, app-config

How do I setup an App.Config for a DLL and make it so that library uses only that config file?

Comment: Did not understand what you want, can you share some more information on what your trying to do?

Comment: I am creating an App.Config and I want the DLL to solely reference that Configuration File.  Is there a way of making the DLL solely reference it since I am using ConfigurationManager?

Comment: Still not clear. Do you want to create kind of a helper class which reads the configuration values? 
You can of course create a helper library with all configuration settings.

Comment: again i don't need them in a Helper Class.  I want them in App.Config for other settings available.